# IBM MQ client 7.5 MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE

Tags: ibm-mq

We've tryed to test connection to the remote queue manager after installing MQ client v7.5 on Windows Server 2019. We've used Rfhutilc for this and got 'Host not available' inspite of the fact that telnet connection to the corresponding address was succecfully established. Also we tryed to connect using MQ client v9.0 with the same result.

AMQERR01.LOG (client v.7.5) reported following details:

```
29.09.2020 15:36:10 - Process(10828.2) User(Администратор) Program(rfhutilc.exe)
                      Host(-) Installation(Installation1)
                      VRMF(7.5.0.6)
AMQ9208: Error on receive from host 'X.X.X.X'.

EXPLANATION: An error occurred receiving data from 'X.X.X.X' over TCP/IP. This may be due to a communications failure.

ACTION: The return code from the TCP/IP recv() call was 10054 (X'2746'). Record these values and tell the systems administrator.
----- amqccita.c : 4065 -------------------------------------------------------
29.09.2020 15:37:56 - Process(10828.1) User(Администратор) Program(rfhutilc.exe)
                      Host(-) Installation(Installation1)
                      VRMF(7.5.0.6)
AMQ9202: Remote host 'X.X.X.X' not available, retry later.

EXPLANATION: The attempt to allocate a conversation using TCP/IP to host 'X.X.X.X' was not successful. However the error may be a transitory one and it may be possible to successfully allocate a TCP/IP conversation later.

ACTION: Try the connection again later. If the failure persists, record the error values and contact your systems administrator. The return code from TCP/IP is 10060 (X'274C'). The reason for the failure may be that this host cannot reach the destination host. It may also be possible that the listening program at host 'X.X.X.X' was not running. If this is the case, perform the relevant operations to start the TCP/IP listening program, and try again.
```

Here is an [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIPin.png) of how traffic data looks like when Rfhutilc refuses to connect to the queue.

As soon as according to the picture there was some code page issue we've tryed to set MQCCSID environment variable with the value 1208 and it helpled.

Also connection attempt via Rfhutilc was succeful while running under another user with login "admin" even though without setting MQCCSID variable.

But I failed to find explanation for this. Did the CCSID of the MQ client differ from system code page of what? And how could I find out default CCSID of MQ client then?

MQ client v7.5 worked just fine on the Windows Server 2012 R2 right after installing. Rfhutilc v7.5 was used both on Server 2012 and Server 2019 for testing.

Comment: 7.5 is out of support since April 2018.   Why not use 9.2?

Comment: According to this [page](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/system-requirements-websphere-mq-v75#Windows_tab) IBM MQ 7.5 is only supported up to Windows 2012 R2.  Even if you had extended support from IBM for 7.5 you are trying a Unsupported version.  V8.0 is also out of support and 9.0 will go out of support in September 2021.

Comment: Just in case its not clear, a 9.2 MQ Client can communicate to a much older server, so you do not need to keep the client and server in sync with regards to MQ versions (they negotiate the capabilities to that which both ends understand).

Comment: @JoshMc Unsupported version of the client doesn't seem to be a reason of the problem. We've also tryed to connect to q manager with only mq client v 9.0.0.10 installed with the same result.

Comment: Both the queue manager and the client machine will have a log called `AMQERR01.LOG`, can you check both for the timestamp when you get the `2538 MQRC_HOST_NOT_AVAILABLE` error and see what is reported, if anything is reported, please edit your question and add the details from the log(s) indicating which log the errors came from. You can wrap your log text with triple backticks on the line before and after to keep it formatted as plain text.  You also indicate that you could connect from a 7.5 install on a 2012 R2 machine, can you confirm it is the same exact version of MQ and using `rfhutil`?

Comment: Is Reverse DNS (REVDNS) enabled on the QMgr? It may be failing on the QMgr attempting to a reverse lookup of the client computer.

Comment: @Matt Pavlovich Unfortunately I don't have access to the queue manager to check the log or anything else.

Comment: @JoshMc - Yes, versions of the MQ and rfhutilc was the same. I edited the question text.

Comment: I think the queue manager AMQERR01.LOG entries will be more helpful pointing out why this is failing, those from the client side that you posted don't give the full picture.